api testing in flask that has a decorator for authentication
I want to test a api of my service named CreateBucket. And this api has a decorator @check_authentication. Now, I want to test the api CreateBucket. But after writing test im getting error for authentication. I tried to mock the authentication. But its not working properly.
class CreateBucket(Resource):
@check_authentication
def post(self, aws_key, aws_secret_key):
data = request.get_json()
bucket_name = data.get('bucket_name')
try:
resp = create_bucket(aws_key,aws_secret_key, bucket_name)
if resp=='fail':
return api_response('fail','Unable to create bucket.')
elif resp=='duplicate':
return api_response('fail','Bucket name must be unique.')
else:
return api_response('success','Bucket Created Successfully.')
except Exception as e:
app.logger.info(e)
return api_response('fail','Unable to create bucket.')

This is my api I want to test. And this is my decorator:
def check_authentication(f):
@wraps(f)
def decorated(\*args, \*\*kwargs):
auth_token = (
request.headers.get("Authorization")
if request.headers.get("Authorization")
else None
)
app.logger.info(f"auth_token: {auth_token}")
if not auth_token:
abort(404, "No token or api key found!!!")
try:
aws_key,aws_secret_key = decode_s3_encoded_key(auth_token)
except Exception as e:
app.logger.info(e)
return api_response('fail','Error in user authentication')
app.logger.info(f"aws_key : {aws_key} , aws_secret_key ; {aws_secret_key}")
return f(aws_key=aws_key, aws_secret_key=aws_secret_key, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
return decorated

I tried this for testing:
@patch("project.s3_service.api.s3.utils.create_bucket", return_value = "success")
@patch('project.s3_service.api.decorators.check_authentication', return_value = " ")
def test_create_bucket_success(mock_create_bucket, test_app):
client = test_app.test_client()
data = {"bucket_name": "test_bucket"}
headers={"Authorization": "test_auth_token"}
response = client.post("/api/v1/create-bucket", json=data, headers=headers)
print("Response status code:", response.status_code)
print("Response JSON:", response.json)  
    
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json["status"] == "success"
    assert response.json["message"] == "Bucket Created Successfully."


But Im getting this error:
Response status code: 400
Response JSON: {'status': 'fail', 'message': 'Error in user authentication', 'msg': 'Error in user authentication'}
